# $scope.$watch is not showing the changing values?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-bootstrap

I am using **accordion directive** from angular-bootstrap and trying to manipulate its `is-open` attribute, so that I can store the value in **localStorage**. I start with **watching** the attribute value but it only shows true all the time:

Controller:

```
$scope.accordionState = true;

$scope.$watch('accordionState',function(newVal,oldVal){
console.log(newVal,oldVal);
} //showing true,true even when accordion is closed
```

View:

```
<accordion-group heading="Main Information" is-open="accordionState">
```

Can anyone guide me what I am doing wrong, and is there a better way to do it? (which I am sure is)

Answer (score 2):

Primitives are passed by value in other words they get copied and your directive is actually changing copy and not the original variable on scope. Try wrapping it into the object:

```
$scope.accordion = {
    accordionState : true
}
```